# How to remove columns where Multiindex levels equal NaN (no value) from a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to remove columns from a dataframe with Multiindex, as for some of the columns my levels equal `NaN` (null). I tried to use dropna() but it works only for rows I assume:
[image]

dataframe is called 'test'
When I do `test.dropna()` is not working. I have 15 levels with IDs:

```
names=['ID14', 'ID13', 'ID12', 'ID11', 'ID10', 'ID9', 'ID8', 'ID7', 'ID6', 'ID5', 'ID4', 'ID3', 'ID2', 'ID1', 'ID0'])
```

Would you have any suggestions how to indicate to remove whole columns with null values in Multiindex (all 15 levels) as well as the corresponding rows?

Thank you in advance! (I am a beginner)

Comment: Do you assign back? `df = df.dropna()` ? Maybe help [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) for better sample data with [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Yes, I tried that but it didn't work :(

Comment: No I am thinking to maybe replace multiindex NaN values with 0 and than try to drop columns... I am looking for this online now!

Comment: What is `print (df.index)` ?

Comment: the print (df.index) shows you the list of index you have in your dataframe

Comment: I know, but in your data?

Comment: ah sorry! Int64Index([    0,     1,     2,     3,     4,     5,     6,     7,     8,
                9,
            ...
            99990, 99991, 99992, 99993, 99994, 99995, 99996, 99997, 99998,
            99999],
           dtype='int64', length=100000)

Answer (score 2):

Try to reset the index and re-indexing again like this:

```
old_idx = df.index.names
my_new_df = df.reset_index().dropna().set_index(old_idx)
```

That's should be able to solve it, hope it helps somehow.

Comment: I also specified df.dropna(axis=1) or df.dropna(axis='columns') but it didn't work...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone! For now I didn't find better way, than just to transpose my dataframe and than delete rows which are NaN in the index... but it worked:

```
test_transposed = test.T
old_idx = test_transposed.index.names
my_new_df = test_transposed.reset_index().dropna().set_index(old_idx)
new_dataset = my_new_df.T
```